# Forcing HTTPS in Symfony PHP causes redirect loop behind AWS load balancer

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, https, symfony-4.2

I am trying to force HTTPS in my Symfony PHP application. The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/routing/scheme.html) on this topic seem pretty straight-forward:

```
# config/routes.yaml
secure:
    path:       /secure
    controller: App\Controller\MainController::secure
    schemes:    [https]
```

Basically just add `schemes: [https]` to the route.

But when I do this in my application and deploy (to an AWS EC2 instance using a load balancer) it appears to create a redirect loop.

[image]

What might be the issue here?

Comment: its actually 4.2 - I have updated the link

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/security/force_https.html) say:

> Forcing HTTPS while using a reverse proxy or load balancer requires a proper configuration to avoid infinite redirect loop

Which in turn takes you [here](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/deployment/proxies.html#but-what-if-the-ip-of-my-reverse-proxy-changes-constantly). Since you can't know the IP address of your load balancer (because AWS), the docs say:

> Some reverse proxies (like AWS Elastic Load Balancing) don't have a static IP address or even a range that you can target with the CIDR notation. In this case, you'll need to - very carefully - trust all proxies.
>
> 1. Configure your web server(s) to not respond to traffic from any clients other than your load balancers. For AWS, this can be done with [security groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-groups.html).
> 2. Once you've guaranteed that traffic will only come from your trusted reverse proxies, configure Symfony to always trust incoming request:
>
> ```
> // public/index.php
>
> // ...
> Request::setTrustedProxies(
>    // trust *all* requests
>    ['127.0.0.1', $request->server->get('REMOTE_ADDR')],>
>
>    // if you're using ELB, otherwise use a constant from above
>    Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_AWS_ELB
> );
> ```

If you follow this steps, and everything else is configured correctly, you should be good to go.